# auto layout stretching image issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to stretch an image from the very left of the view to the very center.  I tried pinning constraints using left 0, bottom 0, and right 300, but it doesn't exactly goto the center.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you know how to set the left, top, bottom, height constraints I will explain you how to set the right constraint, which will cause the imageView to span from the left to the center of the screen. Setting any width constraint will not work, because the width depends is different on every device.

- click your imageView
- choose `Align` -> `Horizontally center in container`
- click on the newly created constraint
- choose the `Size Inspector`
- Change the `First Item` from `Center X` to `Trailing`

The "standard" `Horizontally center in container` causes the `Center X` of your view and its super view to be aligned. If you change the `First Item` to `Trailing` instead of `Center X` you therefore align the trailing edge / right of your view to the centerX of your superview.

[image]

[image]