# What constraints to add to make an UIView take half the size of the screen size

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want my UIView to take half o the screen size, so the constraints should be: 0 for top, leading and bottom. But what about trailing edge ? I do not want to set a constant value to it.

How can I tell IB that the trailing edge should adjust automatically so that the view is half of the screen on all devices ?

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505911/auto-layout-stretching-image-issue/31505991#31505991) I wrote a few days back which just does exactly what you want.

Comment: just add equal widths constraint and set multiplier to 0.5

Comment: @luk2302: for some reason, this doesn't work for me, I still have warnings. The view streches  on all the screen size

Comment: you actually need to give height of view with respect to superview the reason your view stretches all way is you gave opposite constrains.so reverse your constrain & again give multiplier to 0.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed my problem by ctrl dragging from my view to its superview and choose `Equal Widths` and then selected the new constraint and in the `Size Inspector` under `Multiplier` I changed from 1 to 1:2.